# Pear Mail Package Installation onto MAMP

Tags: php, email, mamp, pear

I am trying to install Pear Mail on my MAMP local host.

MAMP VERSION 2.2
PHP Version 5.5.3
Latest Pear Version 1.2.0

I am creating a small app to send email, and I want to use PEAR mail SMTP within my app to process and send Mail. I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/appTest/Mail.php on line 20
```

To install PEAr Mail it self I used TERMINAL with this command:

cd Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.5.3/bin/pear install -a Maill-1.2.0

Before executing this command I also used sudo su to get all admin rights to instal package.

after running the install command in the terminal there was no error and the terminal just jumped to the next line which I assume the installation was successful.

But when I checked the folder in which I installed the Pear Mail package I didn't see as if anything was installed at all and the error message I get seems to confirm this.

Is there anything I have missed out on during the installation..?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You might need to adjust your include_path. First check what directory the Mail package got installed to:

```
Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.5.3/bin/pear list Mail
```

You might see something similar to this:

```
INSTALLED FILES FOR MAIL
========================
TYPE INSTALL PATH
php  /usr/share/php/Mail/mail.php
php  /usr/share/php/Mail/mock.php
php  /usr/share/php/Mail/null.php
php  /usr/share/php/Mail/RFC822.php
php  /usr/share/php/Mail/sendmail.php
php  /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php
php  /usr/share/php/Mail/smtpmx.php
test /usr/share/php/test/Mail/tests/9137.phpt
test /usr/share/php/test/Mail/tests/9137_2.phpt
test /usr/share/php/test/Mail/tests/13659.phpt
test /usr/share/php/test/Mail/tests/rfc822.phpt
test /usr/share/php/test/Mail/tests/smtp_error.phpt
test /usr/share/php/test/Mail/tests/validateQuotedString.php
php  /usr/share/php/Mail.php
```

Then, set your include_path directive to include the directory that you see Mail.php in:

```
In PHP Code:
ini_set('include_path', get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/usr/share/php/');
```

Or

```
In php.ini:
include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/includes:/usr/share/php"
```

Comment: OK running this command this is: `Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.5.3/bin/pear list Mail` the output by my console: Log list of Deprecated files followed by ``Mail' not installed`, I Will try to install it again.......Looking at the steps I have taken in order to install the PEAR mailer do they look correct to you...?

Comment: and what I am trying to install it I get this message in my console:

Comment: `cd Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.5.3/bin/pear install -a Maill-1.2.0
-bash: cd: Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.5.3/bin/pear: No such file or directory` And I am sure this is where the correct folder is

Comment: I see you're using PEAR 1.2.0 - that's a long way out from current. I'd be inclined to upgrade that first, as there may be bugs in such an older version that might be the cause of your problem. Also, I see a few typos in your command that you've included above - try again without the typos first ;)